# Optimize sorting query

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

i couldn't find a way to optimize the following Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl 
WHERE type='51' AND `start`<='2012-01-19' 
ORDER BY end DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

I've tried by indexing each column in a separate index (type,start,end), and all of them in the same index, but MySQL keeps telling me that needs to do a filesort

Is this query just impossible to optimize?

Comment: How many rows are in the table?

Comment: The table contains about 40.000 Rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long you have range comparison in `WHERE` and sort by another field - mysql cannot use index for sorting.

It could if you had `WHERE type='51' AND`start`='2012-01-19' ORDER BY end DESC` or `WHERE type='51' AND`start`<= '2012-01-19' ORDER BY start DESC`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/order-by-optimization.html -- and here is a chapter relevant  to your problem

Answer (score 0):

It depends greatly on the column types and what's all in the table, but all you should really need are indexes on `type`, `start`, and `end` columns.

For an extra boost, you can make an index across `type` *and* `start`.

Comment: Separate indexes won't help. Mysql can only use one index at a time

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is (*) is expanding into rows that are not indexed.

If not, you will most certainly benefit from a [Multiple-Column Index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).

I would experiment and learn to see how to create the order of columns in the index definition with the lowest cardinality (approx unique combinations) of the columns.

Comment: "I would experiment and learn to see how to create the order of columns with the lowest cardinality (approx unique combinations) of the columns." --- and it has nothing to do with original question

Comment: Would you have preferred my response to be "No, it is not impossible to optimize" : only answering the 'actual' question?

Comment: I have already given an answer. And your answer contains irrelevant information. Yes, it is better to say just `NO` instead of giving advices that aren't useful in any way

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers, it made me learn a lot about the issue.

And finally i got it! Looks like this is actually possible to Optimize, or at least to remove that `using filesort` in the `EXPLAIN` sentence.

Here's the indexes i used:

```
    KEY `start` (`start`),
    KEY `typeend` (`type`,`end`)
```

Now executing:

```
    EXPLAIN  SELECT * 
    FROM tbl 
    WHERE type='51' AND `start`<='2012-01-19' 
    ORDER BY end 
    DESC LIMIT 5
```

Leads to:

```
SIMPLE  tbl ref start,type,typeend  typeend 5   const   19  Using where
```

Comment: How long does in take now compared to the time in the question?

Comment: Well, the timing is almost the same because here we're dealing with a really small amount of data (40K rows), the whole table sizes less than 3MB, but i thought it was a great example to ask, because i have many more cases like this with bigger and complex tables, and now i'll be able to start dealing with them

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following:

1. add index (`type`, `end`, `start`)
2. rewrite the query:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM (
     SELECT id -- `id` is the primary key
     FROM tbl
     WHERE type='51' AND `start`<='2012-01-19' 
     ORDER BY end DESC
     LIMIT 5) as ids
   JOIN tbl
   USING (id); -- `id` is the primary key
   ```